# Failed to get EIP-1559 fees error when deploying to ZkEVM polygon using Foundry

Tags: polygon, rpc, foundry, zksync

I have this error

> Failed to get EIP-1559 fees

after running this command

> forge script script/BricksCore.s.sol:BricksCoreScript --rpc-url $POLYGON_ZKEVM_RPC_URL --broadcast

**My script :**

```
contract BricksCoreScript is Script {
function run() external {
    uint256 deployerPrivateKey = vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY");
    vm.startBroadcast(deployerPrivateKey);

    BricksCore bricksCore = new BricksCore();
    ProxyAdmin proxyAdmin = new ProxyAdmin();
    TransparentUpgradeableProxy transparentUpgradeableProxy = new TransparentUpgradeableProxy(
        address(bricksCore),
        address(proxyAdmin),
        abi.encodeWithSignature("intialize()")
    );

    Pool pool = new Pool(address(transparentUpgradeableProxy));

    vm.stopBroadcast();
  }
}
```

**.env file:**

```
POLYGON_ZKEVM_RPC_URL=https://polygon-zkevm-testnet.rpc.thirdweb.com
```

**My Polygon Zkevm account balance :** 0.5 ETH

**PS :** deploying on Ethereum Sepolia testnet works perfectly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to add suffix `--legacy` in forge script